# Web scraping using python to print class div

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I want to print them all as a class of divs for a given site that is within the top div. This would be the part of the website html that I'm interested in printing

```
<div class="game">
  <div class="history-feed__collection">
     <div class="history-feed__card h-card h-card_sm h-card_spades" style="width: 41px; margin-right: 18px; opacity: 1;">
         <div class="h-card__sign">9</div></div>
     <div class="history-feed__card h-card h-card_sm h-card_hearts" style="width: 41px; margin-right: 18px; opacity: 1;">
         <div class="h-card__sign">K</div></div>
     <div class="history-feed__card h-card h-card_sm h-card_diamonds" style="width: 41px; margin-right: 18px; opacity: 1;">
         <div class="h-card__sign">Q</div></div>
     <div class="history-feed__card h-card h-card_sm h-card_clubs" style="width: 41px; margin-right: 18px; opacity: 1;">
         <div class="h-card__sign">2</div>
</div></div>
```

Eu gostaria que o programa imprimisse assim:
"history-feed__card h-card h-card_sm h-card_spades,
history-feed__card h-card h-card_sm h-card_hearts,
... "

I started this code, but I still find problems,
because the code prints only what is contained in the Div and not the name of its class

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\chromedriver')

driver.get('https://card.com')

id = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class]')

for ii in id:
    print(ii.get_attribute('class="hilo-history-feed__collection"'))
    
driver.close()
```

Comment: Hi Gustavo, only on mobile but have you tried beautiful soup: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/   ? You probably want to use ‘find_all(“div”)’, then ‘get(“class”)’.

Comment: Looks like they are using Bootstrap...

Comment: I'll take a look at the documentation to finish my project, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get success with this code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'http://www.card.com'
response = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html5lib')

for i in soup.find_all('div'): 
    print(i)
```

Thanks to everyone who helped

Answer (score 0):

Try Beautiful Soup:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = 'http://www.card.com'
response = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html5lib')
divs = soup.find_all('div')
classes = [div.get('class') for div in divs]
print(classes)
```